# Load UserForm before Save As Dialog is opened

Tags: vba

I have a Software project for Indexing and Archiving of documents.

This is implemented with VBA in Microsoft Word 2007.

**I have this Situation:**

I want to open a user form before the save as dialog is opened.
The opening of the save as Dialog is triggered by a user interaction (click the normal save as button from word)

I tried to handle this with the "BeforeSave" Event but this is executed after closing the save as Dialog. (The save as Dialog is properly not part of the saving process)

So there is no source code to show. This is a generic problem.

Maybe there is a way to start an Event (and open the userform) after the user presses the save as button.

Thank you for your help!

regards,

Korbif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a solution.

In the `ThisDocument` modul, Event `wdApp_DocumentOpen`

I inserted the code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

this prevents that the Save As Dialog is shown before the specific user form is shown.

But thank you for your answer Tom

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it'll save the document with the name `newFileName` under `C:\Your\File\Path`.

```
newFileName = InputBox(Prompt:="Save as", _
      Title:="SaveAs", Default:="Syntax:= C:\Your\File\Path")

ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("C:\Your\File\Path" + newFileName)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i think this is not this what i am searching for.. maybe i was not clear enough. i don't want to save the document. Before the Save As Dialog appears (the normal Dialog from Microsoft Word) a specific user form should appear, on this userform the user can add some generic informations for example "author" , "Component" etc. This is necessary to create the file Name for the Save as Dialog (which should appear afterwards.